# Extract a portion of a string

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to extract a portion of text from a string that can vary. Below are examples. I've tried but can't get the bold part in a clean way. I would prefer to not use VBA.
thanks in advance
.

- /us/travel/**booking_hotel**_*page?myview*
- /en/leisure/**confirmation**_page?myview_WW

Comment: yes, always after the 4° slash and page

Comment: fourth or third ... ?

Comment: fourth (i've put only 3 to simplify). structure is /en/travel/paid/booking_hotel_page?myview ; /en/leisure/organic/confirmation_page?myview_WW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

`=MID(A1,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",CHAR(1),3))+1,FIND("_page",A1)-1-FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",CHAR(1),3)))`

Hard part of the formula is to find `nth` occurance of `/`. `FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",CHAR(1),3))`. The rest is find `_page` and use `MID` to substring.

Good explanation provided [here](http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tip/creating_a_megaformula/).

Comment: brilliant! perfectly working -adapted to the 4 forward slash- really thanks

Comment: what does the fucntion char() stand for?

Comment: Try `CHAR(65)`, it will give you letter `A`. 65 is ASCII code for A. http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: ok, now got it. i've always ignored the Instance_num of the substitute formula. thanks!

Comment: yes, also i've never used that char(). thanks for the explanation